# What's the advantage of Monitor.Enter(object, ref bool) over Monitor.Enter(object)?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, concurrency, c#-3.0

According to the language specification `lock(obj) statement;` would be compiled as:

```
object lockObj = obj; // (the langspec doesn't mention this var, but it wouldn't be safe without it)
Monitor.Enter(lockObj);
try
{
    statement;
}
finally
{
    Monitor.Exit(lockObj);
}
```

However, it is compiled as:

```
try
{
    object lockObj = obj;
    bool lockTaken = false;
    Monitor.Enter(lockObj, ref lockTaken);
    statement;
}
finally
{
    if (lockTaken) Monitor.Exit(lockObj);
}
```

That seems to be a lot more complicated than necessary. So the question is, what's the advantage of that implementation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As always, Eric Lippert has already answered this:

[Fabulous Adventures In Coding: Locks and exceptions do not mix](https://ericlippert.com/2009/03/06/locks-and-exceptions-do-not-mix/)

Excerpt:

> ```
> /* First version of your code, with the Monitor.Enter before the try. */
> ```
>
> The problem here is that if the compiler generates a no-op instruction between the monitor enter and the try-protected region then it is possible for the runtime to throw a thread abort exception after the monitor enter but before the try. In that scenario, the finally never runs so the lock leaks, probably eventually deadlocking the program.
>
> In C# 4.0 we’ve changed lock so that it now generates code as if it were
>
> ```
> /* Second version of your code, with the Monitor.Enter inside the try. */
> ```
>
> The problem now becomes someone else’s problem; the implementation of `Monitor.Enter` takes on responsibility for atomically setting the flag in a manner that is immune to thread abort exceptions messing it up.

Comment: I was about to answer myself after having thought about another answer that was unfortunately deleted before I could comment on it. Made me think more about when exceptions could be thrown, threads being interrupted possibly anywhere, etc. It was quite obvious then that `Monitor.Enter` could return successfully, but before the thread enters the `try` block it could get interrupted. Sometimes this site is too fast to honor all the people who helped finding the answer.

Comment: The link is now dead. As of today, the article can be found here: https://ericlippert.com/2009/03/06/locks-and-exceptions-do-not-mix/

Answer (score 2):

Recently I read in "CLR via C#" that it might not actually be an advantage. The reasoning is that the `finally` block always releases the locked resource, even if the `try` block exited as a result of an unexpected error. That might leave the resource in an undefined state and accessible. The program won't deadlock, but the error may be a lot more subtle and thus harder to find.

It certainly depends on the situation, but I guess the current implementation of `lock` makes most sense if your priority is to prevent deadlocks due to unexpected interruption of threads at the worst spot possible.